# What columns count as lookup column concerning the "List View Lookup threshold"

Tags: lookup-column, settings

I got the following entry in my SharePoint 2010 log file:
"Some lookup fields were omitted from the query results because the list exceeds the lookup column threshold."

I checked the setting (Central Administration, select WebApplication, Resource Throttling) and saw a "List View Lookup threshold" of 8.
But when i check my list i can only see 6 Lookup Columns.

- 5 managed metadata columns
- 1 normal lookup column to another list

So my question is: what type of columns do count as lookup columns? Do "Person or Group" columns count? How about "Created by" and "Modified by"?

Thanks for your help!
regards
tschuege

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly an answer, but it may help you figure it out: The setting says:

"List View Lookup Threshold
Specify the maximum number of Lookup, Person/Group, or workflow status fields that a database query can involve at one time. "

In the API, both Managed Metadata and Person/Group fields inherit from lookup fields; it's also possible that you have some other field types that inherit from lookup.

That being said, it can't possibly be counting everything of one of those types, as there are many "behind the scenes" fields that use them. It also definitely isn't counting dependent lookups as distinct columns for the count, I have one list with 8 of those defined and some other managed metadata etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have read the description of the setting more carefully...
So what you say is that e.g. Person/Column columns count but not those that belong to every content type like "Created By"? right?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Lookup columns are columns located in a SharePoint list which get their values from another SharePoint list.

*Example*:

```
List1 -> ID                    List2 -> Countries
      -> Name
      -> Location
```

In this example we have two lists with their fields. If we want to create the `Location` field as a lookup we create a new column in SharePoint with a type `Lookup` and point it to the `Countries` column in `List2`. So the Location column will be like a drop down menu containing all the items located in `List2` in the `Countries` column.

So the `Lookup` columns get their values from other columns.

You can know which columns are `Lookup` or not by checking their type. You can go to your SharePoint library and view the `Library Settings` where you can see the library columns. If the column type is `Lookup`, so it is a `Lookup` column.

For example the "Created by" and "Modified by" columns are of type `Person or Group` and not `Lookup`.

Concerning the "List View Lookup threshold" the `managed metadata columns`, `Lookup`, `Person/Group` and `workflow status` columns are counted.

Comment: how do we increase the throttle limit?

Comment: @April Please refer to the following [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg491393.aspx)